# Observable property displaying null in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have the following component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../Services/data-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ShowItem } from '../Models/show-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.scss']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

  public showString:Observable<ShowItem>;

  constructor(public datasource:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getShow();
  }

  getShow()
  {
    this.showString = this.datasource.getShow();

    this.showString.subscribe(m=>{console.log(m);});

  }

}
```

and the following view

```
<p>show works!</p>
<p> {{showString|async|json}}</p>
```

This displays the following

> show works!
>
> { "imageUrl": "testimage1.jpg", "showId":
>   "063acbab-66d4-4459-882c-da26625b02ab" }

However if I change the view to

```
<p>show works!</p>
<p>{{showString.imageUrl|async|json}}</p>
```

I get

> show works!
>
> null

The viewModel is as follows

```
export class ShowItem {
    public imageUrl:string;
    public showId:string;
}
```

Why am I getting null for a property that is clearly there?

Comment: Because the property's on the result, not the observable: `(showString | async).imageUrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to access the `imageUrl` property after the `async` has resolved.

```html
<p>show works!</p>
<p>{{(showString|async)?.imageUrl}}</p>
```

Notice the safe navigator operator (`?.`); this will avoid any errors on the template when trying to access the `imageUrl` property before the `async` call has resolved.

Also the `|json` pipe is removed as the `imageUrl` property is a `string`